# Use id as an array's name (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

We have links inside the block:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="james">text</a>
    <a href="#" id="katy">text</a>
    <a href="#" id="julia">text</a>
</div>
```

Ids on different links never repeat.

Trying to create separated array in javascript for each link of this block. The problem is, ids everytime change, I have to do it on the fly.

We should get this:

```
var james = [];
var katy = [];
var julia = [];
```

Link's id = name of the new array.

1) How to code this?

2) How to use then id of the link to call an array? So, we have created them, but in javascript I will do something like

```
$(this).attr("id").push("text"); // on link hover
```

It doesn't work, what is a true way for this purpose?

Comment: What are the arrays for? Do they need to be on the page when loaded or do they get created dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically create `var`s but you can dynamically add properties to an object. So create a "master" object for this purpose:

```
var master = {};
$('a').each(function () {
    master[this.id] = [];
});
```

Push to the array like this:

```
master[this.id].push('text');
```

Comment: this is the CORRECT way, but other answer is the "requested" way :) - note you can also add attributes to the "master" if desired.

Comment: @Mark. Agreed. Please, nobody ever actually implement the example I gave :) I'd feel like a bad influence.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have absolutely no idea why you'd want to do this in separate arrays, you can create the arrays (and anything else you want) using javascript's eval() method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").each(function(){
    eval("var " + $(this).attr("id") + " = new Array()")
  })
})
```

You can use the eval similarly to push.

Box9's answer is much more sensible IMO though.

As a source: http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/dynamic-variables-in-javascript

Comment: +1 on this also as a "requested" and note on the better solution.